# how to get boot option menu with two diffrent os's on two diffrent hdd?

Tags: windows-7, sata, multi-boot

I know when you have two versions of windows or other OS's installed on the SAME hard drive, when you boot your computer you get an menu asking which OS you want to boot.

With my setup right now, I have two version of windows on two different hard drives. When I boot, I don't get that option and it just straight into the windows on "Hard drive 1" every time.

How can I get this option to appear?

This is on a all SATA run system. OS's are windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use EasyBCD
http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/
Install, point it to both installs, and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

One of the vaguest answers would be to install GRUB.  I am unsure of how to configure it to make it actually work but I am sure there is a way to do it.